# Populating resolved with DNS servers

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns, systemd-resolved

I was recently setting up a custom DNS server for my ZeroTier network. I'm using networkmanager and resolved. I added it and it got added to resolved's global list of DNS servers. However, I noticed that my wifi interface [already has a DNS server set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XkUf.png).

I know that NetworkManager probably automatically loads the DNS server from my router, but my  question is, how did *resolved* get ahold of this information and how is it tied to a specific interface? Did NetworkManager tell it when it setup my wifi connection? Is there a  config file somewhere that's telling resolved to tie this specific server to this specific interface?

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** To help put some context around your question, can you please tell us the version of Ubuntu that you're running? Thanks

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 22.04